# Hibernate GROUP BY aggregated field

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have upgraded to spring 2.1, and was forced to move from native query which worked with projection.
So now when I try to execute following query:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT new com.core.model.CoreCountByDateQueryResult( DATE_FORMAT(s.detectedAt, '%Y-%m-%d') as datetime " +
        ", count(*)) "+
        " from CoreSession s " +
        " where s.uid.uid =  :uid " +
        " and s.sessionType = :sessionType " +
        " and date( s.detectedAt ) >= :startDate" +
        " and date( s.detectedAt ) <= :endDate " +
        "    group by datetime")
List<CoreCountByDateQueryResult> getSessionCountByType(@Param("uid") Long uid,
                                                       @Param("sessionType") SessionType sessionType,
                                                       @Param("startDate")Date startDate,
                                                       @Param("endDate") Date endDate);


@Data
public class CoreCountByDateQueryResult {
/**
 * Watch time stamp
 * @return watchTimeUTC
 */
private String datetime;

/**
 * steps_count
 * @return
 */
private long count;

public CoreCountByDateQueryResult(String datetime, long count) {
    this.datetime = datetime;
    this.count = count;
}
```

}

I'm getting an error that **datetime** is not found

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'datetime' in 'group statement'

How can I fix this?

Comment: I think datetime is a reserved word can you try another alias ?

Comment: @YCF_L tried it right now same error

Comment: Yes it seems your query is not correct, you can't group with datetime because it is in another scope

Comment: @YCF_L  it works in MySQL workbench 
 SELECT DATE_FORMAT(s.detected_at, '%Y-%m-%d') as datetime, count(*) 
as count  from core_session as s  where s.user_id=  2 and s.session_type = 'DRINK' group by datetime

Comment: Also note that your query is a native query, you can try also `@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = ...`

Comment: Native query requires usage of projection with interface, it worked fine spring 1.5, but for some reason it not working now. It works only for the interface that are sub-struct of entity

Comment: You should enable JPA logging and see what query is being executed against the DB Server. Copy the query and run it manually against the DB server. Adjust your Query definition and repeat until it works out. Why are you not able to use your previous native query with spring boot 2?

Comment: If you have something that used before but doesn't work anymore you should open a ticket because that sounds like a regression.

Comment: It looks like use of projection is broken in latest Hibernate
[Compatibility with Hibernate < 5.2.11 broken for projections on native queries](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1209)